# .substring не обрезает строку каждый раз. Из-за этого происходит ошибка при создании массива данных

Tags: java

Здравствуйте. Вкратце задача и краткие пояснения.
Ардуино собирает информацию с датчиков и выдает ее в serialPort (фомат данных **названиеДатчика1:значение1*названиеДатчика2:значение2*;**   )
количество датчиков около 60(в тестовом режиме 3). Проблема возникает случайным образом, при запуске приложения.

Грешу на substring.
 String Txtm = IncomingData1.substring(0, IncomingData1.length() - 2);

Вот вывод данных в терминал:

IncomingData1 R0:50.38*R1:20.56*R2:21.94*;

**Txtm R0:50.38*R1:20.56*R2:21.94*;**

SplitData R0

SplitData 50.38

SplitData R1

SplitData 20.56

SplitData R2

SplitData 21.94

**SplitData ;**

Exception in thread "EventThread /dev/ttyUSB0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
    at Main$EventListener.serialEvent(Main.java:129)
    at jssc.SerialPort$LinuxEventThread.run(SerialPort.java:1299)

Process finished with exit code 0

Код:
public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    serialPort = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyUSB0"); /*Передаем в конструктор суперкласса имя порта с которым будем работать*/
    try {
        serialPort.openPort(); /*Метод открытия порта*/
        serialPort.setParams(SerialPort.BAUDRATE_9600, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE); /*Задаем основные параметры протокола UART*/
        serialPort.setEventsMask(SerialPort.MASK_RXCHAR); /*Устанавливаем маску или список события на которые будет происходить реакция. В данном случае это приход данных в буффер порта*/
        serialPort.addEventListener(new EventListener()); /*Передаем экземпляр класса EventListener порту, где будет обрабатываться события. Ниже описан класс*/
    } catch (SerialPortException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}

private static class EventListener implements SerialPortEventListener { /*Слушатель срабатывающий по появлению данных на COM-порте*/
    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {


        if (event.isRXCHAR() && event.getEventValue() > 0) { /*Если происходит событие установленной маски и количество байтов в буфере более 0*/
            try {
                String IncomingData1 = "";
                String NameData[] = new String[10];
                String Data[] = new String[10];
                NameData[0] = "";
                Data[0] = "";

                while (IncomingData1.indexOf(';') < 0) {
                    String IncomingData = serialPort.readString(event.getEventValue()); /*Создаем строковую переменную  IncomingData, куда и сохраняем данные*/
                    IncomingData1 = IncomingData1 + IncomingData;
                }
                                    System.out.println("IncomingData1 " + IncomingData1);

                String Txtm = IncomingData1.substring(0, IncomingData1.length() - 2);//обрезаем '*;'
                System.out.println("Txtm " + Txtm);
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[:]|[*]");//делим строку по символам
                String[] SplitData = pattern.split(Txtm);//6 значений R0/R0(data)/R1/...
                for (int i = 0; i < SplitData.length; i = i + 1) {
                    System.out.println("SplitData " + SplitData[i]);
                }

                for (int i = 0, j = 0, k = 1; i < SplitData.length; j = j + 1, i = i + 2, k = k + 2) {
                    NameData[j] = SplitData[i];/*Делаем отдельный массив R1..Rx*/
                    Data[j] = SplitData[k];//Main.java:129
```

Иногда запуск происходит без проблем(обрезаются 2 последних символа), иногда .ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7(когда символы "*;" не обрезаются).
Подскажите Варианты решения данной проблемы. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static Map<Integer, Double> parseIncomingData(String incomingData) {
    Map<Integer, Double> map = new TreeMap<>();
    StringBuilder sb;
    for (String s : incomingData.split("\\*|;")) {
        String[] split = s.split(":");
        if (split.length == 2) {
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (char ch: split[0].toCharArray()) if (Character.isDigit(ch)) sb.append(ch);
            if (sb.length()!=0) map.put(Integer.valueOf(sb.toString()), Double.parseDouble(split[1]));
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

Comment: Создайте такой метод. В него передавайте ваши данные с ардуины - incomingData. В ответ получите обычную коллекцию типа Map, ключом у нее будет R0, R1, R2 и т.д., а значением -  цифры, которые соответствют указанным ключам. Никаких сабстрингов нет и проблем с обрезанием строки тоже нет. К тому же коллекция приймет любой объем данных в отличии от массива. Если есть необходимось, то можно значение парсить в double, но это уже дело техники.

Comment: TreeMap автоматически сортирует по ключам, т.е. вы всегда при итерации по коллекции гарантировано получите сначала R0, потом R1, R2 и т.д.Если нужен порядок, в котором эти данные записаны в строке, то просто замените TreeMap  на LinkedHashMap.

Comment: Спасибо за предложенный Вами вариант. Мне, чтобы записывать данные нужно иметь Map<Integer, Double>. Я Скорректировал Ваш вариант таким образом: ` private static Map<Integer, Double> parseIncomingData(String incomingData) {
        Map<Integer, Double> map = new TreeMap<>();
        for (String s : incomingData.split("\\*|;")) {
            String[] split = s.split(":");
            if (split.length == 2) map.put(Integer.valueOf(split[0]), Double.valueOf(split[1]));
        }
        return map;
    } ``код`

Comment: Получаю вывод вида 
parseIncomingData(IncomingData1).get(0)> 50.0
parseIncomingData(IncomingData1).get(1)> 20.25
parseIncomingData(IncomingData1).get(2)> 20.56
parseIncomingData(IncomingData1) {0=50.0, 1=20.25, 2=20.56}
Exception in thread "EventThread /dev/ttyUSB0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0"
 at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:638)
 at java.base/java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:983)
 at Main.parseIncomingData(Main.java:88)
 ...

Comment: Подождите, у вас выражение такого вида - R0:50.38*R1:20.56*R2:21.94*, значит при парсе в 1 итерации получим выражение R0:50.38. Его разделим по знаку двоеточия и получим R0 и 50.38. Записать 50.38 в double - не вопрос, а как вы планируете R0 затолкать в integer, если integer - целочисленное значение?

Comment: Можно, конечно, избавиться от всех букв в ключах , оставив только цифры, т.е. превратить R0 в 0, но тогда нужно точно знать, что у вас не будут дублироваться ключи, ведь при попытка затолкать R0 и S0 в двух случаях останется 0, а ключи должны быть уникальные. Если такой ситуации быть не может , то пробуйте мой подкорректированный вариант.

Comment: Ув.Дмитрий Александрович! Я могу избавиться от всех букв в ключах , оставив только цифры непосредственно в скетче ардуино.Тип датчиков будет только один - могу нумеровать просто числом.

Comment: предложенный мной вариант и так избавит вас от всех букв в ключах. для понимания проблемы выведите incomingData и полученный map в консоль. таким образом вы проследите все входные и выходные данные. если программа упадет, то посмотрите, на какой строке это происходит

Comment: Все отлично работает, спасибо большое. Подскажите, пожалуйста, разницу между Double.parseDouble(split[1]) и Double.valueOf(split[1])

Comment: разницы особой нет, поскольку метод valueOf инкапсулирует parse. valueOf появиля позже и в документации рекомендовано пользоваться им.